# Properties of signed measure

Tags: real-analysis

In studying signed measures, I have a question. Let $\mu$ be a signed measure on sigma algebra $\mathfrak{M}$. How can I show that

$\mu^+(E)=\sup\{\mu(F):F\subset E, F\in\mathfrak{M}\}$ and $\mu^-(E)=-\inf\{\mu(F):F\subset E, F\in\mathfrak{M}\}$,

where $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are positive, and negative variation of $\mu$ respectively. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

By Hahn decomposition we have two sets $P,N$ with $P\cap N=\emptyset$, $P\cup N=\text{ the whole space}$, such that $$\begin{align}\mu^+(E)&=\mu(E\cap P)\\\mu^-(E)&=-\mu(E\cap N)\end{align}$$

If $F\in\mathfrak{M}$, $F\subset E$ then 
$$\mu(F)=\mu(F\cap P)+\mu(F\cap N)\leq\mu(F\cap P)\leq\mu(E\cap P)$$

Therefore $$\sup\{\mu(F)|\ F\subset E,\ F\in\mathfrak(M)\}=\mu(E\cap P)=\mu^+(E)$$

Comment: ... as long as Maclaurin does not intend to use these formulas to prove the existence of a Hahn decomposition ...

Comment: @GEdgar Usually this is proved as a consequence of Hahn decomposition and, of course, Hahn is proved without using this. However, I don't know what they could be doing in his text book.

Comment: A small nit: Your argument shows that $M := \sup\{\mu(F) : F \subset E, F \in \mathfrak{M} \} \leq \mu^+(E)$. To show that $M \geq \mu^+(E)$, simply observe that the set $E \cap P$ is feasible for the supremum.